# How to make a view visible in SQL Server for only a user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have 5 views and each of them belongs to a country as illustrated below and I have 20 users per a country who has SQL login

1. `ES_view_test` (20 ES users)
2. `FR_view_test` (20 FR users)
3. `UK_view_test` (20 UK users)
4. `RO_view_test` (20 RO users)
5. `PL_view_test` (20 PL users)

The question is, how can I make ES view visible to only ES users (and the same for the other country views). Every users should only see their specific country's view.

The question is NOT about Row Level Security.

I tried restricting ES view from other country users by denying but this is not manageable. Instead of only enabling ES users. That worked but not an optimal solution.

Comment: why did not use to command grant(GRANT SELECT ON PL_view_test  TO userP) ?

Comment: First - how do you determine the user is an ES user?  Once you have that figured out - then you would have a single view and filter that view based on how you determine the country of the user.  If there is no way to combine these different views into a single view - then use a UNION ALL view that wraps these views, using the code to determine what country the user is from.

Comment: Maybe an inline Table Valued Function where you pass in the user ID or the user permissions and join based on that?